# Calculate Z-height at a given orientation

Tags: z-axis, support-structures

Does anyone know a way to calculate the Z-height and support's volume of an object at a specific orientation (specific x, y, z angles)?

I am looking for an Equation/s or a Python code/s, not a slicer software. Thank you.

Comment: This sounds more like a question for [Mathematics.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [Engineering.SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What do you think about [rotation matrices](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)? I think this is perfectly answerable on mathematics or engineering stacks. The rotation matrix calculates the new position of the coordinates of your mesh, so every coordinate is rotated to a new position, what is left is to find the minimum (can be below the Z=0 plane) and maximum Z height, the difference is the height of the rotated object.